# I can't run a simply Ubuntu Container on Google Cloud Kubernetes!! It just allow to run containers which is hosting a webserver... ONLY?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

first I would like to thank you for been here! I hope you doing well!

So... I'm trying to **create an Ubuntu:20.04 container** on Google Cloud Run or Kubernetes..

Whenever I try to deploy this **Dockerfile** on Google Cloud Run

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
```

**It fails, and shows an error:**

[The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqqS7.png)

Apparently, this happens due to lack of a webserver inside the container?

**To fix this, I followed** [this guideline](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstarts/deploy-app-container-image#python_1) by Google itself.

So, basically, inside the **Dockerfile**, I just added couple of code lines:

It just installs python, flask and gunicorn and set default to automatically run app.py when container is created.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN apt-get install -y python3 && apt-get install -y pip && pip install Flask gunicorn
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 app:app
```

Also, I created a new file "app.py" that import Flask.

**Its just a simple webserver...**

```
# Python run this file, and when someone send a request to this Ubuntu:20.04 container ip on port 8080 
# a simple text is showed "Hello World".

import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    target = os.environ.get('TARGET', 'World')
    return 'Hello {}!\n'.format(target)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

And boom... **It works**!! We have Ubuntu:20.04 running on Google Cloud Run... **the error was fixed!**

So, Google Cloud Run works like:

**if there's a webserver running on that port:**

```
 then GCR LAUNCH CONTAINER
```

**if there's NO webserver running on that port:**

```
 GCR DOESN'T launch container...
```

**IN RESUME:**

**I just want to run a python code on ubuntu container.
just like I run in my local machine, that works perfectly.
also this python code doesn't use flask or any webservice, it runs independently, make some compute works and comunicate through an external database.**

**So, my question is, how to deploy a container image that doesn't host a web service, on Google Cloud Run or Kubernetes, just like I create on my local machine and acess through /bin/bash CLI...???**

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is, how to deploy a container image that doesn't host a web service, on Google Cloud Run or Kubernetes, just like I create on my local machine and access through /bin/bash CLI...???

There might be a misunderstanding of the Google services here.

## Google Cloud Run

Runs your web application (a web server) in a container. It is not a service for other things than web applications (e.g. only http).

Key features: Keeps your server up and running, and can scale out to multiple instances.

## Google Kubernetes Engine

Runs **services** (processes that starts and then are meant to stay running) in containers, both stateless, as `Deployment` and stateful as `StatefulSet`. Also support for **jobs** that is tasks that perform something and then terminates.

Key features: Keeps your server up and running, and can scale out to multiple instances. Can re-run Jobs that failed.

## Google Compute Engine

If no one of the above fits your needs, you can always go low level and run and maintain virtual machines with e.g. Linux and containers on it.

Comment: Hello Jonas! Thank you for taking ur time to answer my question!! I'm glad!!
Your explanation about Google Cloud Run was very good, now I got it! it's all about web application...
But what about kubernetes? are they also only for web application?

Comment: I have explained the use case for Kubernetes in my answer as well. It is for services and jobs, but it sounds like you want something more like a virtual machine?

Comment: Yeah, your explanation about kubernetes was very good too!! 
I was the problem , I actually trying to run a container in kubernetes without being running a web service but can’t find it how or any topic related..

Comment: Does your container basically run to completion, meaning it starts, runs some code to do something and when it finishes it terminates?

Comment: @GariSingh I do think it runs, but google automatically terminates or don't allow to complete, because it keep listening to an webservice port just like in cloud run...

Comment: Can you explain your use case a bit more?  You want to run a container on Cloud Run or GKE, be able to create a shell session to the container, run some code and then exit?  Do you have to have a shell into the container?